# How can I prompt a user to choose a location to save a file?

Tags: c#, savefiledialog

In my main Form I have a method called SavePDFDocument():

```
private void SavePDFDocument()
{
    PDFWrapper pdfWrapper = new PDFWrapper();
    pdfWrapper.CreatePDF(horizontalPictureScroller1.GetPictures(), "pdfDocument.pdf");
}
```

As you can see, right now I'm manually typing in a name for the file. I'd like to ask the user to choose where to save it and what name to give it.

This is the CreatePDF() method I'm using above:

```
public void CreatePDF(List<System.Drawing.Image> images, string filename)
{
    if (images.Count >= 1)
    {
        Document document = new Document(PageSize.LETTER);
        try
        {

            // step 2:
            // we create a writer that listens to the document
            // and directs a PDF-stream to a file

            PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create));

            // step 3: we open the document
            document.Open();

            foreach (var image in images)
            {
                iTextSharp.text.Image pic = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(image, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);

                if (pic.Height > pic.Width)
                {
                    //Maximum height is 800 pixels.
                    float percentage = 0.0f;
                    percentage = 700 / pic.Height;
                    pic.ScalePercent(percentage * 100);
                }
                else
                {
                    //Maximum width is 600 pixels.
                    float percentage = 0.0f;
                    percentage = 540 / pic.Width;
                    pic.ScalePercent(percentage * 100);
                }

                pic.Border = iTextSharp.text.Rectangle.BOX;
                pic.BorderColor = iTextSharp.text.BaseColor.BLACK;
                pic.BorderWidth = 3f;
                document.Add(pic);
                document.NewPage();
            }
        }
        catch (DocumentException de)
        {
            Console.Error.WriteLine(de.Message);
        }
        catch (IOException ioe)
        {
            Console.Error.WriteLine(ioe.Message);
        }

        // step 5: we close the document
        document.Close();
    }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Did you take a look at [SaveFileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog.aspx)?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
     Stream myStream ;
     SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();

     saveFileDialog1.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*"  ;
     saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2 ;
     saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true ;

     if(saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
     {
         if((myStream = saveFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)
         {
             // Code to write the stream goes here.
             myStream.Close();
         }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I believe [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969773.aspx) describes what you are looking for:

```
// Configure save file dialog box
Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog();
dlg.FileName = "Document"; // Default file name
dlg.DefaultExt = ".text"; // Default file extension
dlg.Filter = "Text documents (.txt)|*.txt"; // Filter files by extension

// Show save file dialog box
Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();

// Process save file dialog box results
if (result == true)
{
    // Save document
    string filename = dlg.FileName;
}
```

Comment: I think the higher-level 'System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog' is more appropriate in this case. Does anyone happen to know what the difference is though? It's not obvious after looking at the MSDN.

Comment: Thanks, the question is more difficult though. How can I integrate this SaveFieldDialog functionality with my code above? Notice I'm using New FileStream(). Any suggestions?

Comment: @Serg look at the example code I posted in my answer; it is handling a Stream object.

Comment: @Nathan - I would be very interested to know the differences too.

Answer (score 2):

A useful link: [How to: Save Files Using the SaveFileDialog Component](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sfezx97z%28VS.85%29.aspx)